# Unable to take snapshots or use git in XCode 4.6

Tags: git, snapshot, xcode4.6

After upgrading to Xcode 4.6 whenever I attempt to create a snapshot or use Git I get this popup.

> Please tell me who you are.
>
> Run
>
> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>
> git config --global user.name "Your Name"
>
> to set your account's default identity.
>
> Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
>
> fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Faisal@(null).(none)')

Im new to Git and version control in general so I was hoping someone could explain what this means, why its suddenly started appearing, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run these commands in the terminal:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Replacing `you@example.com` with your email address, and `Your Name` with your name. This information will tell Git who you are, and how to mark commits made by you. If Git doesn't have this information, it will not be able to commit.

Comment: Thanks enthrops, I attempted to follow that before It didn't work for some reason but it has now! Any idea as to why this information might have suddenly disappeared on upgrading?

Comment: Not really sure, I updated to 4.6 recently as well, and my git config file was not touched. Your update probably wrote over that file, weird

Comment: Probably you just updated `git` to a version that demands that information, where it wasn't before.

Comment: I tried this and it says on the prompt command not found. @enthrops

Comment: @Camus You have to install git